How to Use ytdl-core in a React Native Project?
I am trying to use the ytdl-core library in my React Native application to download YouTube videos, but I'm encountering some challenges.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Installed ytdl-core using npm install ytdl-core.
Tried importing and using the library as follows:
javascript
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';

const getVideoInfo = async (url) => {
  try {
    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
    console.log(info);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching video info:', error);
  }
};

Attempted to run the app, but I encountered errors related to Node.js modules or polyfills, such as:
Cannot find module 'stream'
process is not defined
What I’ve tried:
Installed polyfills for stream, buffer, etc., using packages like stream-browserify and react-native-polyfills.
Adjusted the metro.config.js file to include extraNodeModules for these polyfills.
Despite these efforts, the app fails to work correctly.
Questions:

Is it possible to use ytdl-core directly in a React Native project,
or are there fundamental limitations?
Are there alternative approaches or libraries available for
downloading or fetching metadata for YouTube videos in React Native?
If someone has successfully integrated ytdl-core with React Native,
could you provide a working example or configuration?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Please note, ytdl isn't mantained now, as the author says. In the meantime he suggests to use Distube
